# What is the standard scratch?

Tags: code-golf, math, number

In golf, the standard scratch of a course is calculated using this formula:

```
(3*num_of_3_par_holes + 4*num_of_4_par_holes + 5*num_of_5_par_holes) - difficulty_rating
```

Your task is to calculate the standard scratch of a golf course, given these 4 inputs.

You should take input in any standard form in the format

```
[num_of_3_pars, num_of_4_pars, num_of_5_pars], difficulty rating
```

but if it saves bytes, you many take input in a different way.

You should output the final result by any accepted method on meta, such as returning from a function.

Shortest code wins because this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)!

Comment: Will all inputs be integers and at least 1? (Also, will the output always be positive?)

Comment: Can we take inputs reversed?

Comment: As trivial as this is, a few test cases would be nice.

Comment: Interesting, a code golf about golf.

Answer (score 31):

## Scratch, [145 bytes](http://scratchblocks.github.io/#?lang=oto&script=adi()-%20temi%0A(a)kuati(thadi%0Aadi()-%20temi%0A(b)kuati(thadi%0Aadi()-%20temi%0A(c)kuati(thadi%0Aadi()-%20temi%0A(d)kuati(thadi%0Ama(((c)-((a)%2B(d)))%2B((4)*(((a)%2B(b))%2B(c)

<sup>-2 thanks to boboquack

-??? because writing it in [Oto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oto-Manguean_languages) is shorter than English</sup>

(Because Scratch is the standard scratch.)

[image: adi()- temi (a)kuati(thadi adi()- temi (b)kuati(thadi adi()- temi (c)kuati(thadi adi()- temi (d)kuati(thadi ma(((c)-((a)+(d)))+((4)*(((a)(b))+(c translation: ask()and wait set(a)to (answer ask()and wait set(b)to (answer ask()and wait set(c)to (answer ask()and wait set(d)to (answer say(((c)-((a)+(d)))+((4)*(((a)+(b))+(c]

Here's a sample run:

[image: a=18,b=13,c=41,d=23;answer=124].

Answer (score 19):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
JḊ~æ.N
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/r4Y6uusPL9Pz@//9vaGBgoKNgCCGAGAA)

#### How it works

```
JḊ~æ.N  Main link. Argument: [a, b, c, d]

J       Indices; yield [1, 2, 3, 4].
 Ḋ      Dequeue; yield [2, 3, 4].
  ~     Bitwise NOT; yield [-3, -4, -5].
     N  Negate; yield [-a, -b, -c, -d].
   æ.   Dot product; yield
        (-3)(-a) + (-4)(-b) + (-5)(-c) + (-d) = 3a + 4b + 5c - d.
```

Answer (score 10):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 24 bytes

```java
(a,b,c,d)->a*3+b*4+c*5-d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYyxCoMwFEV3v@KNiUah1U6lHbt1ciwdXhIjsRrFRKGI357G0Decx4V7T4cr5uPUmE5@/LTwXgsQPVoLT9QGtgRAG9fMCkUDD9iOBIocRHaQR4pISa@wh8XfYx268NZRSxiCjdRu1qZ9vQHn1tIohyBVcPMEGWeCSZrfMS0znlaZSC@59BDvGqv117pmKMbFFVMwud4QVShyYmdWsorSo7Unu/8B)

Comment: Yeah, shorter than Python \o/

Comment: This provides proof that Java and Javascript are the same language!

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, 13 <del>14</del> bytes

```
{3,4,5,-1}.#&
```

Thanks to @GregMartin. Take input as a length-4 list.

Comment: Thanks to "but if it saves bytes, you many take input in a different way", I think you should take input as a length-4 list and shorten the second solution to `{3,4,5,-1}.#&` (13 bytes).

Comment: You are right..

Answer (score 6):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 22 bytes

```hs
(a#b)c d=3*a+4*b+5*c-d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/XyNROUkzWSHF1lgrUdtEK0nbVCtZN@V/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgoqChrGykaapgvl/AA) Usage: `(3#2)5 7` yields `35`.

This not so nice input format is one byte shorter than the straight forward solution:

```hs
f a b c d=3*a+4*b+5*c-d
```

---

**Point-free and nice input format:** (23 bytes)

```hs
(-).sum.zipWith(*)[3..]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyflfrauck5iXXpqYnqrgHBCgrFvLlWYb819DV1OvuDRXryqzIDyzJENDSzPaWE8v9n9uYmaegq1CQVFmXomCikKaQrSxjpGOaayC@X8A) Bind to `f` and call with `f [3,2,5] 7`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Julia 0.5](http://julialang.org/), 15 bytes

```julia
!v=v⋅[3:5;-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f9fscy27FF3a7Sxlam1rmHsf8VoQwMDAx1DMNYxjVWosVMoKMrMK/kPAA)

Comment: Is `⋅` three bytes, or am I miscounting? Would `.*` be an improvement? edit: Never mind—missed the summing part.

Comment: Yes, three bytes. `.*` only performs element-wise multiplication; it doesn't take the sum of the products.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 28 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d:3*a+4*b+5*c-d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ0knWSfFylgrUdtEK0nbVCtZN@V/QVFmXolGmoaJjoKxjoKRjoKhpuZ/AA)

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 7 bytes

```
3r5×⁸S_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9@4yPTw9EeNO4Lj////H22oo2Cko2Ac@98IAA)

-3 bytes thanks to Erik The Outgolfer!

### How it works!

```
3r5×⁸S_  Main link: a, the pars as a list and b, the difficulty rating

     S   The sum of
3r5        [3, 4, 5]
   ×       each element times
    ⁸      the left argument (a)
      _  Subtract the right argument (b)
```

Comment: Standard way to make lists is omitting `[]` but you can use `3r5×⁸S_` to golf this more (`3r5` -> `[3, 4, 5]`, `⁸` = left argument to differentiate it from the `S`, `×` is commutative).

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript, 24 bytes

```
(a,b,c,d)=>3*a+4*b+5*c-d
```

Answer (score 4):

## Perl6, 16 characters

```perl6
3* *+4* *+5* *-*
```

(Yepp, that is a sub.)

Sample run:

```
> say 3* *+4* *+5* *-*
{ ... }

> say (3* *+4* *+5* *-*)(4, 3, 2, 1)
33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYKsQ899YS0FL2wREmAIJXa3/1lzFiSBZDUsdBTMdBWMdBVNNuJiFjgIQmQCFNa3/AwA)

Answer (score 3):

## C#, 24 bytes

```c#
(a,b,c,d)=>a*3+b*4+c*5-d
```

Answer (score 3):

## x86-64 Machine Code, 14 bytes

```
8D 3C 7F 8D 14 92 8D 04 B7 01 D0 29 C8 C3
```

A function following the System V AMD64 calling convention (ubiquitous on Gnu/Linux systems) that takes four integer parameters:

- `EDI` = num_of_3_par_holes
- `ESI` = num_of_4_par_holes
- `EDX` = num_of_5_par_holes
- `ECX` = difficulty_rating

It returns a single value, the standard scratch, in the `EAX` register.

**Ungolfed assembly mnemonics:**

```
; int ComputeStandardScratch(int num_of_3_par_holes,
;                            int num_of_4_par_holes,
;                            int num_of_5_par_holes,
;                            int difficulty_rating);
lea   edi, [rdi+rdi*2]    ; EDI = num_of_3_par_holes * 3
lea   edx, [rdx+rdx*4]    ; EDX = num_of_5_par_holes * 5
lea   eax, [rdi+rsi*4]    ; EAX = EDI + (num_of_4_par_holes * 4)
add   eax, edx            ; EAX += EDX
sub   eax, ecx            ; EAX -= difficulty_rating
ret                       ; return, leaving result in EAX
```

Just a simple translation of the formula. What's interesting is that this is essentially the same code that you would write when optimizing for *speed*, too. This really shows the power of the x86's `LEA` instruction, which is designed to *l*oad an *e*ffective *a*ddress, but can do addition and scaling (multiplication by low powers of 2) in a single instruction, making it a powerful multi-purpose arithmetic workhorse.

Answer (score 3):

## dc, 14 characters

```
?3*?4*+?5*+?-p
```

The numbers need to be passed on separate lines.

Sample run:

```
bash-4.4$ dc -e '?3*?4*+?5*+?-p' <<< '4
> 3
> 2
> 1'
33
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@/9/eWMveREvb3hSIdQv@/zfhMuYy4jIEAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 14 bytes

```matlab
@(a)[3:5 -1]*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999BI1Ez2tjKVEHXMFYr8X@aRrS5tam1pbVprOZ/AA)

About twice as long as the [MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130192/32352). I initially literally ported this to MATL, but it turned out `iY*` is longer than just `*s`. Note that the input `a`, containing the holes in order and then the difficulty, should be a column vector.

Comment: As question says you can take the input in any format if it saves bytes, this works for 14: `@(a)[3:5 -1]*a`. Input is a column vector of `[3 holes; 4 holes; 5holes; difficulty]`

Comment: @TomCarpenter Oh, I thought the list + number part was compulsory. It's a bit oddly phrased: "You should... but you may". I guess I'll amend my answer then.

Answer (score 2):

### [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
f(a,b,c,d)=3a+4b+5c-d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0/f8/TSNRJ0knWSdF09Y4UdskSds0WTflf0FRZl5JTp5GmoaljpmOsY6ppiYXQsxCx0LHRMdYU/M/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Swift 3](https://swift.org), <s>25</s> 19 bytes

I realised you do not need the `var f=`, because you can call it like a Python lambda:

```
{$0*3+$1*4+$2*5-$3}
```

[Test it online!](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/595d1428ce92ef1217b41e45)

**Usage:** `{$0*3+$1*4+$2*5-$3}(a,b,c,d)`, where `a,b,c,d` are the parameters.

Answer (score 2):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 7 bytes

```
'πS
```

Explanation:

```
'π         Push 345
           The character ' pushes the next character's index in the codepage plus 100.
           The characters ", + and * do that same thing except add a different number.
           This means that in Neim, all 3 digit numbers can be expressed with 2 characters.
           This commit was pushed 8 days before the answer was posted.
          Get the characters
          Vectorised multiply with the input
           Sum the resulting list
     S    Subtract the input
```

Alternative program: `3ᛖS`

Instead of pushing `345` and then getting the characters, creates the array `[1 2 3]` using `3`, then adds 2 to each element with `ᛖ`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3/X/18w4e5E5o@zJ3aDaTXBAMZXf//RxsqGCkYx3IZAwA)

Comment: `This commit was pushed 8 days before the answer was posted.` well, you don't actually need this.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Sure I don't. But I also don't need the explanation. Would you like me to remove that?

Comment: Basically you don't have to worry about non-competing since meta consensus changed.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer I do worry about non-competing because the meta consensus is subjective and unclear. But in this case, there's no reason to complain about it being there. You're using up more time than you otherwise would you didn't post that comment.

Comment: For some reason, most Neim chars in inline code blocks look like ? boxes.

Comment: @CalculatorFeline That's probably because your browser doesn't support the characters. [Here is a screenshot](https://puu.sh/wCkfo/8a21842156.png).

Comment: Chrome 58 Mac. For some reason non-inline code blocks work perfectly and so does `3`. How strange.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 30 bytes

```c
e;f(a,b,c,d){e=3*a+4*b+5*c-d;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z/VOk0jUSdJJ1knRbM61dZYK1HbRCtJ21QrWTfFuvZ/bmJmnoZmdUFRZl5JmoaSakpMnpJOmoahjpGOsY6RpiZQCQA)

Comment: No need for an extra variable. Just assign to `a`.

Answer (score 2):

## [,,,](https://github.com/totallyhuman/commata), 12 bytes

```
↻5×↻4×↻3×↻-#
```

### Explanation

Take input 4, 3, 2, 1 for example.

```
↻5×↻4×↻3×↻-#

              implicit input                  [4, 3, 2, 1]
↻             rotate the stack clockwise      [1, 4, 3, 2]
 5            push 5                          [1, 4, 3, 2, 5]
  ×           pop 2 and 5 and push 2 * 5      [1, 4, 3, 10]
   ↻          rotate the stack clockwise      [10, 1, 4, 3]
    4         push 4                          [10, 1, 4, 3, 4]
     ×        pop 3 and 4 and push 3 * 4      [10, 1, 4, 12]
      ↻       rotate the stack clockwise      [12, 10, 1, 4]
       3      push 3                          [12, 10, 1, 4, 3]
        ×     pop 4 and 3 and push 4 * 3      [12, 10, 1, 12]
         ↻    rotate the stack clockwise      [12, 12, 10, 1]
          -   pop 10 and 1 and push 10 - 1    [12, 12, 9]
           #  pop 12, 12, 9 and push the sum  [33]
              implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

```
∧5⟦₁↺b;?z×ᵐġ₃+ᵐ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HHctNH85c9amp81LYrydq@6vD0h1snHFn4qKlZG8jQ/f8/2lDHSMdYxyj2fxQA)

-2 thanks to [Fatalize](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41723/fatalize).

Comment: `∧5⟦₁↺b;?z×ᵐġ₃+ᵐ-` is 2 less bytes

Comment: @Fatalize It would've been 3 less bytes if there wasn't a bug with leading integer and input.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 39 bytes

```
,[->+++<],[->++++<],[->+++++<],[->-<]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fJ1rXTltb2yYWykBiQZm6NrF2ev//AwA)

Takes input and prints output as ASCII characters; for example, the value 99 would be represented as c.

#### Explanation:

```
,                                       Take the first input in Cell 0
 [      ]                               While the data being pointed to (Cell 0) is nonzero
  ->+++<                                Decrement Cell 0 and add 3 to Cell 1
                                        Now 4 times the first input is in Cell 1
         ,                              Take the second input in Cell 0
          [->++++<]                     Add 4 times the second input to Cell 1
                   ,[->+++++<]          Take the third input in Cell 0 and add five times its value to Cell 1
                              ,         Take the fourth input in Cell 0
                               [    ]   While the data being pointed to (Cell 0) is nonzero
                                ->-<    Decrement Cells 0 and 1
                                     >. Print the value in Cell 1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Gallina](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual003.html), 38 bytes

```
Definition f a b c d := 3*a+4*b+5*c-d.
```

Answer (score 2):

## Excel VBA, 20 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from the range `[A3:A6]` of which `[A3:A5]` represent the number of `3`,`4` and `5` par holes, respectively and `[A6]` represents the difficulty. Outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?[3*A3+4*A4+5*A5-A6]
```

The above is a condensed version of the call

```vba
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=3*A3+4*A4+5*A5-A6")
```

Where `"=3*A3+4*A4+5*A5-A6"` is given to be the formula of an anonymous cell, as indicated by the `[...]` wrapper, and `?` is the deprecated version of the `Print`  call with an implicit `Debug.` by context

#### More fun Version, 34 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function with same I/O conditions as above.

```vba
?[SUMPRODUCT(A3:A5,ROW(A3:A5))-A6]
```

The above is a condensed version of the call

```vba
Debug.Print Application.Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(A3:A5,ROW(A3:A5))")
```

Where `"=SUMPRODUCT(A3:A5,ROW(A3:A5))"` is given to be the formula of an anonymous cell, as indicated by the `[...]` wrapper, and `?` is the deprecated version of the `Print`  call with an implicit `Debug.` by context. In this version, the range of `[A3:A5]` and the row numbers of that range (`ROWS(A3:A5)`) are passed as arrays

#### Excel Version, 18 bytes

Of course, the versions above lend themselves thusly to excel versions of

```vba
=3*A3+4*A4+5*A5-A6
```

and

```vba
=SUMPRODUCT(A3:A5,ROW(A3:A5))-A6
```

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>25</s>  23 bytes

```r
cat(c(3:5,-1)%*%scan())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCNZw9jKVEfXUFNVS7U4OTFPQ1Pzv4WCmYKJgrHpfwA)

Comment: `sum(scan()*3:5)-scan()` is slightly smaller

Comment: thank you. I usually don't try `scan` when there are multiple inputs like this, but whaddya know!

Answer (score 2):

## [Cubix](https://github.com/ETHproductions/cubix), 36 bytes

```
w;r5*U4I;I3*r;UW;;r;<\r/;r-I/+p+O@;w
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy5Nyqz4/7/cushUK9TE09rTWKvIOjTc2rrI2iamSN@6SNdTX7tA29/Buvz/fxMFQ0MFYwUzMwA)

```
      w ; r
      5 * U
      4 I ;
I 3 * r ; U W ; ; r ; <
\ r / ; r - I / + p + O
@ ; w . . . . . . . . .
      . . .
      . . .
      . . .
```

[Watch It Run](https://ethproductions.github.io/cubix/?code=ICAgICAgdyA7IHIKICAgICAgNSAqIFUKICAgICAgNCBJIDsKSSAzICogciA7IFUgVyA7IDsgciA7IDwKXCByIC8gOyByIC0gSSAvICsgcCArIE8KQCA7IHcgLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4gLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4KICAgICAgLiAuIC4K&input=NCAxMSAzIDY2&speed=20)

A fairly linear program that winds back around onto itself a few times.  Basic steps:

- `I3*r;U;` get the first input, multiply by 3 and clean up stack
- `I4*/r\` get next input and multiply by 4. Rotate result down.
- `Iw5*Ur;w<;r;;W` get next input, multiply by 5 and clean up the stack
- `I-r;w;` get last input, subtract from par 5 result and clean up stack
- `/+p+O\@` add to par 4 result, bring par3 result to top add, output and halt

Answer (score 2):

## HP-15C (RPN), 14 bytes

Instruction hex codes:

```
41 C4 F5 FC C5 F4 FC FA C5 F3 FC FA 31 FB
```

Readable version:

```
001 {       44  1 } STO 1
002 {          33 } R⬇
003 {           5 } 5
004 {          20 } ×
005 {          34 } x↔y
006 {           4 } 4
007 {          20 } ×
008 {          40 } +
009 {          34 } x↔y
010 {           3 } 3
011 {          20 } ×
012 {          40 } +
013 {       45  1 } RCL 1
014 {          30 } −
```

The four numbers are loaded into the stack in order before running the program.

Comment: Nice first answer. Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
`-Σz*d345
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P0H33OIqrRRjE9P///9HG@sY6ZjG/jcHAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 15 bytes

```
&3*&4*+&5*+&-.@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0pNK81LT9W1tPj/X81YS81ES1vNFIh19Rz@/zdVMDRQMFMwMgAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 12 bytes

```
*3+V*4+W*5-X
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=KjMrVio0K1cqNS1Y&input=NSwzLDQsNw==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 14 bytes

```
3*>4*>5*>>++,-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLz89J@//fWMvORMvOVMvOTltbR/f///8m/43/G/03BAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Batch, 28 bytes

```
@cmd/cset/a%1*3+%2*4+%3*5-%4
```

Can't believe I'm tying with Python!

Comment: Just curious, do you need the `cmd/c` - if the rest is in a batch file won't it just work?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah `set/a` normally doesn't print its result, so I would have to assign it to a variable and echo it, which costs far too many bytes. However, when you use it interactively then it does print the result. Invoking `cmd/c` fools it into printing the result.

Comment: Would the rules require the @ sign, which only hides the command?

Comment: @trlkly I'm not actually sure, so I've been erring on the side of caution.

Answer (score 1):

## [cQuents](https://github.com/stestoltz/cQuents), 14 bytes

```
#|1:3A+4B+5C-D
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Sy4sTc0rKf7/X7nG0MrYUdvESdvUWdfl/39jBRMFUwVDAwA)

Input is `3par 4par 5par diff`. cQuents is not at all built for this type of problem, but it still did fairly well.

### Explanation

```
#|1               Append 1 to the end of the user input - call it n
   :              Mode: sequence
    3A+4B+5C-D    Each item in the sequence equals the first input times three plus
                  the second input times four plus the third input times five minus
                  the fourth input. The last input, n, which came from the program's
                  parameters, prints the nth item in the sequece.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
3LÌ*O²-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f2Odwj5b/oU26//9HG@somOgomMZyGQIA)

Comment: You can replace `3L` with `ā` as the first input will be a list of length 3 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 12 bytes

```
{6,3>.*:+\-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP2fU/e/2kzH2E5Py0o7Rrf2f91/Q4VoYwUTBdNYAA)

-1 thanks to [Challenger5](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61384/challenger5).

Takes input as `difficulty rating [num_of_3_pars num_of_4_pars num_of_5_pars]`.

Comment: Use `6,3>` instead of `345Ab` to save a byte.

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, 9 bytes

```
-s*V}3 5E
```

[Try it here.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=-s%2aV%7D3+5E&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+5%5D%0A2%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

Takes input as `difficulty rating\n[num_of_3_pars, num_of_4_pars, num_of_5_pars]`.

Comment: The code you posted and the TIO don't match.

Comment: @jacoblaw Sorry that's what you get for writing code by hand >_<

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 23 bytes

```
~[.;3,]zip{~3+*}%{+}*\-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/vy5az9pYJ7Yqs6C6zlhbq1a1WrtWK0b3/38jhWhDBSMF41gA)

Takes input as `difficulty rating [num_of_3_pars num_of_4_pars num_of_5_pars]`.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP>=7.1, 43 bytes

```php
[,$x,$y,$z,$d]=$argv;echo$x*3+$y*4+$z*5-$d;
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b0c8b2cd1e914a5e837999357436abd50ec304ff)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 7 bytes

```
3:5*si-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/39jKVKs4U/f//2gLBUsFQ4NYLlMA)

Input vector times range `3:5` minus the second input. Contrary to my Octave answer, it's actually shorter to have the inputs as two separate inputs, and shorter to element-wise multiply, then sum, than to do a direct dot product.

Answer (score 1):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 14 bytes

```
?:*3+:*4+:*5-:
```

Functionally equivalent to [this](https://repl.it/JRg7/0).

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), <s>13</s> 8 bytes

```
35Ř←*Ʃ←-
```

Takes as input from stdin inputs separately in the following order:
[num_of_3_pars,num_of_4_pars,num_of_5_pars], difficulty_rating

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 12 bytes

```
{-y-/x*3+!3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/Nqlq3Ule/QstYW9G49n@agp66hoahgpGCsbWJprWGiYKZgoW1sTmQaQwUNLU219T8zwkA)

Called like `f[1 2 3;4]`. Takes the number of par 3/4/5 holes as one list of three values, and the difficulty rating as the second arg.

- `x*3+!3` generate `3 4 5`, multiplying by the first input
- `-y-/` equivalent to `(-y)+/x`, or `(+/x)-y`. In this instance, the leading `-` negates the entire `y-/...` expression.

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `as`, <s>8</s> 7 bytes

-1 thanks to Aaron Miller

```
2ʀ3+uJ*
```

Takes input as `par3 \n par4 \n par5 \n difficulty`.
[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=as&code=2%CA%803%2BuJ*&inputs=3%0A4%0A5%0A1&header=&footer=)

```
2ʀ3+uJ*
2ʀ        # Push the range [0, 1, 2]
  3+      # Add 3: [3, 4, 5]
    uJ    # Append -1: [3, 4, 5, -1]
      *   # Multiply the list by its counterpart in...
          # the (implicit) input, and...
          # Print the sum of the result (s flag)
```

Comment: [7 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=as&code=2%CA%803%2BuJ*&inputs=3%0A4%0A5%0A1&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 24 bytes (6 instrs)

```
00000000: 2a020202 28000000 26020203 2a000100  *£££(¡¡¡&££¤*¡¢¡
00000010: 22000002 f8010000                    "¡¡£ẏ¢¡¡
```

```
scratch 4ADDU $2,$2,$2      // p5 *= 5
        2ADDU $0,$0,$0      // p3 *= 3
        SUBU  $2,$2,$3      // p5 -= diff
        4ADDU $0,$1,$0      // p3 += 4 * p4
        ADDU  $0,$0,$2      // p3 += p5
        POP   1,0           // return p3
```

I ordered the instructions to avoid as many short-term data dependencies as possible.

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 18 bytes

Takes input as `<3-par>,<4-par>,<5-par>,<difficulty>`

```
Ci',G,3*$4*+$5*+$-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##zVt5c9u2Ev9fnwK100qKJVm@cvhZbuMkTd02ccZ25/WNx1UgEZKYkgRDgpHV66vn7YKHeIAiWJ@aSSyRwO5vT1wLdyFm3Nl55npfTNvlniD@wu8Qm4pZh5iCeYJzy29MPG4TYdqMxK0sxtzwsUcdA/5EL/AX/JuyRvRAeHTMRnT8e6MxtqjvkyOP@mP6Er/vNwh81tbWzgQ06BCPTU0fmPoEqJDP1DPpyGI@NJANDTYhw6HpmGI4bPnMmrT3G/IFftYlDdkxIZO8xMY9XzYYkIvL7HMKz/rZR6PMoyWPFx4jcwYMqGE6U8I@Mw8UiF@pT8YzCrIi32/zjD1oMrS5wYDu99TyWQr3e9NlRtd0iEEFTR6bE@JwaQ3oDsx6pk@FWLTa@0mTFH1oMMTuQH7ZA1G22hf7@92ty0ynCffIsEOGBJgyJ7CZRwVr5UjlGCmYob38wBLINPvmAll2Ck/zOLKW6VHXZY7R4p7RCgm320lzBjqrkhy8ZKnVHyg6UWScEWMOccEIghlkwUTOPtRCVS2GcYuijc5npk/mpmURX3DwAQrfxIyRERj8dyaIy31TmNzJedx8ZlpsaHHu@kD0z78zFBkZo0OgwyIplyNzL0sAWwyjN0UvHYcOlZZbPofIs8wxRAnYNhFG3UJwNyvu@vvAnxHoOAKOgkto0jxJBLrQYBg2kD7TwdYpbylaFN@nqX@mVsAInywjBjkpuOD7iAd@XckE3UY2apcLMuJCQKoCzivFGobtqqQzHR/yY6sfNqkWUAsB9sjyL5d8CaAoPNhVZuccC@7GiTOfaBKy2TDzmAg8J@V5xUiMmqSAIZswdnNoKlXA3bTwdwCzH2vsDMIYAcWDR4LJZ2IYP4xMEv/M4oufkgHEJF1TpCsap8qlgkKs@d4jVe9RsXfK59LYm37kgsoAxmR3UxJlQjCUsa2Wu19X3CLpUVutlH5kwlMcj32mFFm@yTtVik/cop3Qkt6CpCzmTMVM7bDhuzzdyNXgZWvJIhWagQUDrqQmRwiCIwSxQB@klR832gmrUWBaRvgwz08w281ObPDJEOYdmTlH9iUMjBb7FHDBMtbByUE8nEHy4baNI1RxpoCDT26OAGYtkD4k/eJEotCqOyBbmVbSR4o4B@XUcrLmgcWCoLtdrIWjbqZf1FFNPnbDWDHtItg0g8taDMA7PJxESUbZzFA2m7iQfS6hU4youkvcEnvJ7qtlaK5VavrcC1i1bQdkezWnD7XNkW5WAKFLHztWk4@8qYFrkLMFZCybUG8KkeAIWL64cvmE00BY0vTcBZmQgwmo3KE2Oyy@HZMDDJvDRuOcQzzh4gZCexRMOySAvDUxNscYasCFGphvJpvjHjb1LT4nBp87hAfCDUTU3N8c@xKYiesi5DkcSomHQ5vCvHgYmTAEAIZILb0iJ4uwJTPJtS8vzWbnTWfn8aPdxxuP9uBf90u0SAvTFznCPBQmRkxbNnXTlNJZKs545C2gka3l7zDnpTgnM9wDmTJTb9I5zltkrZWYOE3qQkH2Mp8LojaZZVmpvxUerBM53h5AOjzMzltXpJy@IppSWkvPqfvF8C@49JY@uS0Nctv65LY1yO3ok9vRILerT25Xg9yePrk9DXJP9Mk90SD3VJ/cUw1yz/TJPdMg91yf3HMNclYNN9YJi59r0NPxPFYjLnSM@7pGYOgEmlEjMnTM@6qGL@vExqyGu@h48w91/EXHYX6qRVCH4p9r@2T9FRt7DKcIusTjRzj56@pk7L@RzbFzDTYbOmw8ZCOHu1O5p6viQ5cjsHryKsHoNMKlh4lLDbmB3Bp1CAWUaguVSGi2G8UBWwoQjvYwZZpRr1Lw5ofmSsfI7ugq58FaE@q8FHLDq2I6s7F12V5FKDOj2sCFVVEjbykuaF1czvHUNnkp9g30gxeGccsOoHLZDarhp13EdxaM8LBB3APIrg7IxwjybWAJ07UW9wDysQ7IzTCxCDYF7zHMz6avWlzePtjNTR20X0uVciOw@D1g/FoH4m8I8fWVy52yRH3LVtcyuy8D6JN3HYRF5niM2JvAwi/66gODFm23VUn6yBRzE1a1NbLSPwj63cn5jWL@R0dd38h8@O7VPdjzGx18fyG@k9N7gPeXDrwhwvv1XvD9BvgU3nemXMQXgFME7srtdr7cwn6xcqqQPj4AAhrqGSm5HOlzGelweSG5xCczesJkjw70pDlS8zmqwUdLng7yibbxSzZlMhzi/f5KwvtI2AjwxFRu24MofLKCw7/NPPQ6LQuo/5NFvTx10wUeH8Tpoorb0xvoUJDGRmls/jmrfoyPkIiSZXgG9q@MEWOTJDTwvU3w5RQtj@Cijc9qfHV1ro3PrdAfcWR5j6/2C5sHjtBdwTnLFVy/E3ZdsYbTttHN2Ol9hZ0ekB5W@8I1/eFbmSzDyq2oRqLf3dp@qut3SZlXC9aZ@X2FtgaAr5Ixbnm8Wpm0FXsZ0QGsDstHyNKfU1caWsw5FrjZPuHOtZP5rWf8kYZ8p9KmXMSDlJh5jN2tjONbV8T4OipTnucU9HiGehxzB8dNJ1EmuEtI2L97P8EY8wWKtIF/qFaETfNilDtAVD@AbJrN3kduOpKd014msmTjCysZypPeGNMcJJNU6ksd6UW9q3f06igHwWuo441SHfJk2IdJknrhu/5hq7e909vd@0CaPWKSN2RwSLbI9g7Z3VN2MICvrWNl4IkVG1j00VqEer7qkAUqLim77U09HrijRUZ9HWJRe2RQ8sc@@QMlkyzbcYHU1eW92UbKgNRBtnIyJb4W6UAq4Kpda8zTdAAzcgCY9wsCREwTx/xo8Gt1VQckGc11ojE6UwqTUV650AAl7Hw4ILvPoupm/H0wIHtPy/tltpyBxYVEghUcsjuArpb7OC33sh4y1EBr487k7mfFfv6vpQbIjWqxr@T6xwQinlG9Zlvp3AXav6Zp66ysdGZ1BS4BcvnF6Z4pSTq681BZvBWm83pHKRChhs5A80uEc1qKMx3oV@1losh4UaPKDbIVbjctpmJT6HjzRMPRuNxrk3U5eAvgxdnL4@Oo2rXK65a1KIUS9NJ6lJwoxdp15WkUfmST1niWPQdsdyCsjUGzqWHpk1JRdYLg/qVNgq@O0E5W6CiDPlwDp41bQ8x35WI@VOMqDLsUWBHPL7kjPG6R7y0@r1bIASrkZ@b7sJCit30Ehuo7oLUS15aaEtNRdd16s0PUxRswj7zKcDfqOHy46hjIM71PAbj1HShiMHiwmmj@rwmaOGJizpjzEPYWUF84uxzjfw/Xgb5DBzpnnm3iUrRxM0kRb/6xK1PozC3XEQDkQ0OWhFOLfAxstyKxS62jXvuV@ijWoFQi@oiIfgQUOJubw8Tar1Pkki2gqub2Y8INr6bWY9fNstvQYHeB7P6Ldc9dWTRdrL8vqjuc836Fk96VC6zMSqm7dVlhoTKpEqHSdwYqq6mV0l7mpIUh@bZkPbxVUXU86eXqsq7cXUy9UrFzTZrh7U1Js5FduYR3laQUrsfkro@fXFvGq7FRPVzx5oS6OF59WWL9HK85mQKmhhMynzEHlvgcGHsyqoQJNgW2E1i9GxUF8vUK7rLXmRI0J8haFpHIgwXFnl55Mi9U4UXgcqUq62/lGVp8eTd/aVcrBbKrMXMF@YktRhwSDxZbeV7gitwduGI2jzq@ln8gbaMhc@Ksn3GbhZee58wRZO5xZ9rBowA@B@MQ4MSzcMOp9Nrr09OT032i6p47fA87JNf6e5CubSqGAC5/CpMSIbwIchw5bnSNpVF34bBsmwkB8DHFCmPlQf819kPpYOUsRIERQ1@NsbhYpVVrthLi6gBd0qZFskpykT6L5FaIXVvkanHri1oqJn6@7HR2O3udJ/8H)

### Explanation

```
C                   - Set implicit output to number mode
 i',G               - Use numbers instead of charcodes for 0-9. Then split by commas.
     ,              - Reverse stack so the 3par is at the top.
      3*            - 3par * 3
        $4*+        - 4par * 4, then add to 3par
            $5*+    - 5par * 5, then add to total
                $-  - total - difficulty
<implicit>          - Print it
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
[ { 3 4 5 } v. - neg ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVeWChIqVshOLcpLzQGLKSQWF@cnFysUFKWWlFQWFGXmlShYc3FVcykAQbWCCRAbKhgpGCvUKtRCxYzNwRJmChZIgiAxY6BCU7BY7f9oMN8EzC/TU9BVyEtNV4j9Xw3kgm20y00sUCguSUzO1vsPAA)

*-1 thanks to @Bubbler*

The quotation takes the input as `difficulty list`.

- `{ 3 4 5 } v.` Take the dot product between the input list and `{ 3 4 5 }`.
- `- neg` Subtract the difficulty rating from the dot product.

Comment: `- neg` is one byte shorter than `swap -`.

Answer (score 0):

## TI-Basic, 19 bytes

```
Prompt A,B,C,D:3A+4B+5C-D
```

Alternatively (21 bytes):

```
3Ans(1)+4Ans(2)+5Ans(3)-Ans(4
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 27 bytes

```
D,g,@@@@!,3 4 5 1ECBcB*0$_s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HAQgUdYwVTBRMFQxdnZ2SnbQMVOKL/8dzqaTbxXP5//9v8t/4v9F/QwA)

### How it works

```
D,g,        - Create a function called g...
    @@@@    - ...that takes 4 arguments...
    !,      - ...as a list. e.g.     [4 3 2 1]
    3 4 5 1 - Push 3 4 5 1; STACK = [[4 3 2 1] 3 4 5 1]
    EC      - Collect;      STACK = [[4 3 2 1] [3 4 5 1]]
    Bc      - Zip;          STACK = [[4 3] [3 4] [2 5] [1 1]]
    B*      - Products;     STACK = [12 12 10 1]
    0$_     - Negate;       STACK = [12 12 10 -1]
    s       - Sum;          STACK = [33]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 13 bytes

```
3n*4n*5n*&+n-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/984T8skT8s0T0tNO0/3/38LLlMuEy4jIwA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](http://desmos.com/calculator), 21 bytes

```
f(a,b,c,d)=3a+4b+5c-d
```

[image]

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/k8ejofnanc)

Input is a function where \$a=3\ \text{par holes},b=4\ \text{par holes},c=5\ \text{par holes},d=\text{difficulty rating}\$

Example Test Case:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╨E⌡u╥Diüaë¬~▼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d045f575d24469816189aa7e1f&i=%5B3,2,5%5D%0A7)

If I can find a way to read in the array and the number as is instead of evaluating them from string, this program will be shorter.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 66 bytes

```
list($a,$b,$c,$d,$e)=$argv;echo eval("return 3*$b+4*$c+5*$d-$e;");
```

---

---

first attempt:

## PHP, 145 bytes

```
<?php $a=$_SERVER['argv'];$b=[0,3,4,5,-1];$r=array_map(function($x,$y){return$x*$y;},$a,$b);echo array_reduce($r,function($i,$c){return$i+=$c;});
```

### Ungolfed:

```
<?php
$a = $_SERVER['argv'];
$b = [0,3,4,5,-1]; // the first element always contains the filename, and is hereby disregarded
$r = array_map(function($x,$y){return $x*$y;},$a,$b);
echo array_reduce($r, function ($i,$c) {return $i+=$c;});
```

---

---

With 10, 5 and 3 holes respectivly, and a difficulty of 5, it's to be called with `$ php codegolf.php 10 5 3 5`

Note: it throws a warning, as we multiply a string with zero. Add 1 byte for the error-supression-operator to get rid if that.

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 13 bytes

```julia
v->[3:5;-1]'v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvu/TNcu2tjK1FrXMFa97H@aRrShgYGBjiEY65jGairU2CkUFGXmlfwHAA)

improvement of [Dennis's Julia 0.5 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/130005/98541)